# Dirac Delta function expressed in terms of molecular orbital basis set

Tags: hilbert-space, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

In the book of Helgaker [1](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119019572) on page 16 is written that for a complete one-electron molecular orbital basis, the Dirac delta function may be written in the form of:

$$\delta(\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{x'})=\sum_{P=1}^{\infty}\phi_P(\mathbf{x})\phi^{*}_P(\mathbf{x'}).$$

Why is this the case?

Comment: I don't have access to your book, but this is a completeness relation for the eigenfunctions of a Sturm-Liouville operator. Typically, Legendre polynomials, or Hermite functions, etc... obey such completeness relations.

Comment: ...for example, [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432086/why-is-the-set-of-eigenfunctions-of-a-hermitian-operator-complete). This is the celebrated [resolution of the identity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432086/why-is-the-set-of-eigenfunctions-of-a-hermitian-operator-complete).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The eigenfunctions $\phi$ from my example are not Legendre polynomials or Hermite polynomials to my knowledge. But I can see now that the answer is indeed involving the resolution of the identity. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use Dirac notation in my answer. Denote by $\left| P \right>$ the vector associated to the wave function $\phi_P(\mathbb{x})$. The completeness relation reads
\begin{equation}
1 = \sum_{P=1}^\infty \left| P \right>\left< P \right|
\end{equation}

Now remember $\phi_P(\mathbb{x}) = \left<\mathbb{x}|P\right>$ and $\left<\mathbb{x}|\mathbb{x}^\prime\right> = \delta(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{x}^\prime)$.

Hence
\begin{equation}
\delta(\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{x}^\prime) = \sum_{P=1}^\infty
\left<\mathbb{x}|P\right>\left<P|\mathbb{x}^\prime\right>
\end{equation}

which yields your equation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't the $\delta$ in your equation the Kronecker delta rather than the Dirac delta function?

Comment: No it is the Dirac delta because the operator $\hat{\mathbb{x}}$ has a continuous spectrum

Comment: So you mean that ⟨x|x⟩ would not be equal to one, but it would be δ(0)? How is δ defined in the way you use it, e.g. as a measure or a distribution?

Comment: It is used as a distribution. The eigenvectors of a continuum spectrum are not normalizable, but they can be normalized via a Dirac delta. $\left<x^\prime|x\right>$ is the probability amplitude of finding a particle at $x$ in $x^\prime$, indeed it is 0 if it is two different points and otherwise a dirac delta of 0 because its integral need to evaluate to 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular representation of the Dirac delta function. Take a general state $\psi(x) = \sum_P c_P \phi_P(x)$ as a test function which is expanded in the basis $\phi_P(x)$. Using the fact the basis is complete and orthonormal, one can show that $$ \int d^nx’ \delta(x-x’) \psi(x’) = \psi(x) $$ and $$ \int d^n x’ \delta(x-x’) = 1 $$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see why the above two equations from you hold which involve the integrals over x'. However, I still cannot see why the equation of my original post holds which is over the sum of all basis functions. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Insert your expression for the delta function into the two integrals above and use the fact the basis is orthonormal to verify that they hold.